# Problems when changing the title of Table of Contents in spanish

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, babel, thesis

I would appreciate it very much if someone would be able to provide some answer to my problem. I have been reading and searching the Web and StackExchange for some time and trying several possible solutions, however, none of them work.

I am trying to change the title of the Table of Contents in Spanish (I am using the package babel btw) which is "Contenido" by default and I want to change it to "Índice".
I read the babel package documentation and still can't manage to change it.

The phstylee.cls is mandatory in my case because I am writing my thesis.
Below you can see the initialization and the problematic part.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{phstylee}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotate}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subcaption}     %para usar multiples figuras con multiples captions
% \usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % para subequations
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.8}
\usepackage[algoruled,linesnumbered,noline,algosection]{algorithm2e}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1} % Changes Tabular's box size. Ojo que cambia tambien el 

\addto\captionsspanish{%
\def\bibname{Referencias}%
\def\tablename{Tabla}%
\def\listfigurename{ÍNDICE DE FIGURAS}
\def\listtablename{ÍNDICE DE TABLAS}
\def\spanishcontentsname{ÍNDICE}
\def\contentsname{ÍNDICE}
}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{ÍNDICE DE FIGURAS}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{ÍNDICE DE TABLAS}
\renewcommand{\spanishcontentsname}{ÍNDICE}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{ÍNDICE}

\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.99} % figures using 90% or more of the available space in a page will become in a new pure-image page. 

\allowdisplaybreaks

\addtolength{\textheight}{00mm}\addtolength{\voffset}{-20mm}
 \linespread{1.2}


\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\spanishcontentsname}{\'Indice}
%=============================================================================
%------------------------- TITLE ---------------------------
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
%
%\cleardoublepage
%\input{0_FirstPage.tex}
%
%\cleardoublepage
%\input{0_Title.tex}
%\cleardoublepage
%
%\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%---------------------- ACKNOWLEDGMENT ---------------------
%\onehalfspacing
%\cleardoublepage
%\input{Acknowledgment.tex}
%------------------------- ABSTRACT ------------------------
%\linespread{1.2}
%\cleardoublepage
%\input{Abstract.tex}
%-------------------------- INDEX --------------------------
\linespread{1.4}

\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\listoftables

\linespread{1.3}
%------------------------- CHAPTERS ------------------------
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\end{document}
```

The possible solutions that I found so far are  `\renewcommand{\spanishcontentsname}{ÍNDICE}` and
`\renewcommand{\contentsname}{ÍNDICE}` for the old babel, and `\addto\captionsspanish{% \def\spanishcontentsname{ÍNDICE} \def\contentsname{ÍNDICE} }`

The funny thing is that I manage to change the name of the list of figures and the list of tables, but not the name of the table of contents.
I apologize in advance for the length of the question and the orthographic and grammatical mistakes. Any comments, suggestions and help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

UPDATE:
A friend of mine has the same problem and send me another `phstylee.cls` file. I just put it into my main folder and eureka, it changes the table of contents name and several other little aesthetic problems. So it's solved now.

PS: Thanks a lot to Mico for the time.

Comment: Is the `phstylee.cls` document class file available online?

Comment: Yes, http://www.hpjava.org/papers/NOWbook/phstyle.cls

Comment: I don't have access to the `phstylee` document class. For sure, `\usepackage[spanish]{babel} \addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\'Indice} \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\'Indice de tablas} \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\'Indice de figuras} } ...` gives the expected output when used with the `article`, `report`, and `book` document classes.

Comment: It changes the list of tables name and the list of figures name, however it doesn't change the toc's name T.T

Comment: How do you generate the table of contents? I do it with `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: Same, `\tableofcontents` (You can see it in the code above)

Comment: OK, I figured out what's going on. Please see the answer I posted a couple of minutes ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `phstyle` document class provides the following, rather idiosyncratic redefinition of the `\tableofcontents` macro:

```
\def\tableofcontents{\@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
 \fi\thispagestyle{plain} \@makeschapterhead{Contents} 
 \@afterheading
 \@starttoc{toc}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi}
```

Observe the hard-coded string `Contents`. Maybe the nicest thing that can be said about this redefinition is that it cannot have been undertaken with the needs of `babel` users in mind.

The remedy? Just add the following code to the preamble of your document:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{Contents}{\'Indice}{}{}
```

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{phstyle} 
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\patchcmd' macro
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{Contents}{\'Indice}{}{}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\addto\captionsspanish{%
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\'Indice de tablas} 
    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\'Indice de figuras}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\chapter{Uno dos tres}
\section{Ola}
\section{Adios}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work =(

Comment: A friend of mine have the same problem and send me another phstylee.cls file.
I just put it into my main folder and eureka, it changes the table of contents name and several other little aesthetic problems.

Comment: @GustavoBittner - It works for me if I use the `phstyle` document class, for which you provided a link. See the MWE I just posted to prove my point. If you're using a *different* document class, then naturally all bets are off.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. It is solved with my friend's file.